# ServiceStack rest with null?

Tags: rest, servicestack

I'd like to make R a nullable int (and b a nullable bool). I can hit `/api/test/1/2` no problem but `/api/test/null/2` causes SerializationException

```
KeyValueDataContractDeserializer: Error converting to type: Input string was not in a correct format
```

I tried doing `/api/test//2` but it ignored the double slash and thought it was {Ids}.

How do I make R nullable?

```
[Route("/Test")]
[Route("/Test/{Ids}")]
[Route("/Test/{R}/{E}")]
[Route("/Test/a/{Ids}/{R}/{E}/{b}/{f}")]
public class Test
{
    public long[] Ids { get; set; }
    public int? R{get;set;}
    public int E{get;set;}

    public bool? b { get; set; }
    public float f { get; set; }
}
public class TestService : Service
{
    public object Get(Test a)
    {
        return JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `null` in your route is treated like a string literal which obviously is not a valid number. Basically you want to avoid passing in null in the first place (i.e. avoid specifying it), e.g instead of:

```
/api/test/null/2
```

You can do:

```
/api/test?E=2
```

Comment: Hmm, so routes are for conveniences and I can do whatever I want? cool +1&accepted(when SO lets me)

Comment: Yes custom routes are for user-defined conveniences, in addition to pre-defined routes and auto-generated Routes. read the [wiki page on Routing](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing) for more info.